# Why was this question closed? how could I improve it?

Tags: discussion, closing

I made a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/106207/20456), which was initially commented as non-answerable. However, a mod agreed with the question, and there have been some interesting comments so far.

Even though the question was initially severely downvoted, it came back up and it's now breaking even.

However, now it is closed as "Non-constructive", and I would like to know how can I fix it to get it reopened.

My defense for this question is:

- IMO, it amply falls into "Gameplay strategies and tactics", which is an appropriate question type per the FAQ
- It is a real problem a serious gamer may have
- It is answerable, by somebody who has experienced and solved this problem
- It is practical, as any player, from casual to pro may find use in this question and its answer
- It is not chatty or open-ended. It poses a specific problem, and asks for specific answers.

Edit: Once again, it got closed. Now the question has several good answers and 11 upvotes vs the original 4 downvotes.

Comment: I think I was a little hasty with my close vote.  I thought about it some more afterwards, and while there's no way we can say, "If you do this, you'll always succeed", we can definitely provide some advice and experiences to help you along.  Sorry about that.

Comment: 10 people think it should be closed, 4 people think it should be opened, two of whom are mods *(and one of whom is the top answerer)*.  I don't think the mods should override the community's decision just because they don't agree *(and because there's a popular meta-post about it)*.  I personally think it should be closed - it is **wayyyy** too generic to warrant any useful answers, as evidenced by the completely generic answers given.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It takes much more determination to vote for reopen, thank just clicking for closing, so I don't think open and close votes in general can be objectively compared, but I digress. I would like to hear your opinion on the five defense points I posted above. (by the way, the meta post became popular _because_ the question got closed and reopened, not the other way around)

Comment: Real problem or not, I don't think mods unilaterally reopening it should be done.  They're supposed to be exception handlers, not reversing the community's votes.

Answer (score 4):

A  good subjective question focuses on the how and the why without just asking for a shopping list of things you can do. I think your question is fine up until to the point where you ask for "any methods" (inviting a list) rather than just flat out asking how to solve your problem. It's a tiny difference, but it can make all the difference in the answers you receive.

Of course, the answers also need to focus on the how and why rather than the what. The burden is by no means just on the shoulders of the asker, but it takes a great question to invite great answers.

At any rate, I've already sort of asked this question [on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51572/whats-the-name-for-those-times-when-your-attempts-to-get-a-task-done-right-even) and got [relevant material](http://www.gladwell.com/2000/2000_08_21_a_choking.htm) that would make for an excellent good subjective answer.

Comment: Sounds fair to me

Comment: If there's more than one "correct" answer, its a list.

Comment: @djsmiley2k A question with no one correct answer is a _subjective question._ We allow subjective questions.